# Get option value from select inside Smarty PHP loop (JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

So I need to append and un-append divs which contain the values of whichever option was selected, problem is that the method of displaying the select values in the first place is via. a for-each loop using Smarty PHP templates, and I am unable to find any documentation on how it can be achieved using this.

**What I've tried:** as you will see below I've tried creating a JavaScript variable inside the template file, but it only ever returns the value of the first option selected. I cannot figure out why I am only ever getting the first value taken from the loop.

For example, if I have two items in a select 'A' and 'B', when selecting the value option, I will always just receive 'A' back as the value.

**Smarty Template Code:**

```
<select class="my_select" name="vlans_{$NetworkDTO->id}[]">
    {foreach from=$arrNetworkDTO item=NetworkDTO name=arr}
    <option class="addOvmCardList" id="addNameDisk{$strIdTpl}" value="{$NetworkDTO->name|escape}">{$NetworkDTO->name}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('a.addListOVM').click(function(){

    $(".my_select").change(function() {

        $('.addCardOVM').append(
              '<div class="divform"><label>' + $(this).val() + '</label>' +
              '<a href="">-</a></div>'
                );              
    });                             

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="my_select">
  {foreach from=$arrNetworkDTO item=NetworkDTO}
   <option value="{$NetworkDTO->name|escape}">{$NetworkDTO->name}</option>
  {/foreach}
</select>

<script>
  $("#my_select").change(function() {
    $(".addCardOVM").append("<div>" + $(this).val() + "</div>")
  });
</script>
```

**Edit:** To get the value of a selected option on button click:

```
$('a.addListOVM').click(function(){


        $('.addCardOVM').append(
              '<div class="divform"><label>' + $(".my_select:selected").val() + '</label>' +
              '<a href="">-</a></div>'
                );

});
```

Comment: Updated my answer based on your code above (to get the select value on button click).

Comment: Try `$('.my_select:selected').val()`!

Comment: @Sim Surely a `<select>` element is never "selected", so that will just return nothing. The `<option>` inside would be `$('.my_select :selected')` (with a space) but `.val()` should take care of that for you.